# Can clustering be used for log-odds scores?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, bioinformatics

I have data which looks like [this](http://icb.med.cornell.edu/education/courses/introtobio/PAM30). As you can see the data is symmetric and its not exactly a distance matrix. They are log odds ratios. And the diagonal values are higher than non-diagonal elements.

I want to know if normal clustering techniques could be use for such a scenario. When I looked online, all the clustering methods use distance metric and diagonal values are zero. Is there a way for me to adopt this table for clustering analysis.

I just want to know which amino acids are similar to each other and categorize them in to clusters based on their similarity. Can anyone suggest a good clustering technique for this?

Thanks!

Comment: Diagonal elements are 0 because objects have 0 distance from themselves or perhaps more formally cluster centers have 0 distance from themselves.

Comment: How do odds ratio relate to your problem of comparing amino acids?

Comment: If the entries of the matrix are odds ratio, then why aren't the diagonal entries $\infty$? The odds ratio (and therefore the log odds ratio) will be $\infty$.

Comment: because x/x=1 and log(1)=0.  But that said, these can't be log odds ratios because they should be 0 on the diagonal and they're not.  Maybe something to do with that log(2)/2 bit at the top?

Comment: I suspect they're not log-odds *ratios* but log-*odds*. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_matrix#Log-odds_matrices

Comment: The odds ratio in a $2 \times 2$ table is $p_{11}p_{00}/p_{01}p_{10}$ where $p_{ij}$ are the cell probabilities. If the $2 \times 2$ table is composed of the same items with itself, all of the elements will reside in either the $(1,1)$ or $(0,0)$ cell. Therefore the odds ratio is $1/0 = \infty$. I don't know what $x/x = 1$ has to do with it.

Comment: @onestop, how could log-odds be interpreted as distance between two points? That would be a univariate measure.

Comment: As the questioner says, "its not exactly a distance matrix". See my link to Wikipedia, but as i understand it they're something like log-odds of transition probabilities.

Comment: Well, log-odds ratios wouldn't  be "exactly distances" either, which is how I interpreted the statement. I'm not clear on how that log-odds matrix is applicable here but let's wait for clarification I suppose

Comment: It may be worth noticing that when the last two rows and columns ("X" and "*") are removed, the matrix naturally becomes a (degenerate) distance matrix by subtracting each element of a row from its diagonal entry. (The last three rows, "B", "J", and "Z", have zero distances to other rows.)  The degeneracy can then be lifted by adding any positive constant matrix to these distances.  Whether any of this is meaningful depends on what these "log odds ratios" actually represent.

Comment: The values in the table represent how evolutionarily conserved the amino acids are. That is why the diagonal values are high. For e.g., we expect A to replace itself with no problem. The log odds score for this 6. Here A to D is -3, which means there is less possibility for A to become D during the course of evolution. And A to W is -13, which means its even harder for A to be W.

Log odds score is calculated by =>
(probability of amino acid 'a' being replaced by 'b')/(background freq. of 'a' * background freq. of 'b').

Comment: And this table is not calculated by me, its been there for long and been computed by people who have worked extensively on this. I wanted to see if I can classify amino acids based on these scores.

Comment: @onestop: I think it is actually log odds score. Sorry about that confusion.

Comment: @whuber: And like you said, i think we can remove B, J, Z, X and *.   B, J, Z and X are not actually amino acids.

Comment: Would people posting answers kindly include a plot so we can see how well their algorithm works?

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is to go beyond k-means and hierarchical clustering to somewhat more modern methods (if you consider 1990s to be "modern", that is).

Many clustering methods such as DBSCAN do *not* require your distance to be *metric*. The whole notion of a *metric* is of low relevance for data mining, as databases may contain duplicate records, so at best you have a pseudo-metric anyway.

Many just need some kind of similarity measure. It could even measure similarity instead of distance, that is just a different sign for the threshold to them.

DBSCAN needs a threshold. OPTICS when using the $\xi$ method for extracting clusters also needs them to bear some semantics, i.e. a drop in distance of 10% being interesting enough to start a new nested hierarchical cluster.

If you have a metric (or pseudo-metric), that can bear performance benefits. If you already have a distance matrix, these are moot, because that already means you computed the $O(n^2)$ similarities.

K-means, while very popular, has much stronger restrictions. In particular, the mean must minimize the distances, i.e. updating a cluster center with the mean of the objects must improve the criterion function. This will likely not hold for you, if you can compute distances from mean vectors at all.

You might want to have a look at "Generalized DBSCAN" to understand how loose the dependency on the distance function is. It's just a method for selecting "neighbor" objects. But you can in fact plug in any other definition of "neighbor".